# Expose multiple similar database fields as enumerable collection

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django (1.8) Model for an underlying database table that has multiple columns that are logically a fixed-size array. For example:

```
from django.db import models

class Widget(models.Model):
    # ...
    description_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # ...
```

I would like to be able to access these columns as if they were a collection on the model instance, e.g.:

```
instance = Widget.objects.get(...)
for description in instance.descriptions:
  # do something with each description
```

My primary motivation is that I am exposing this model via Django Rest Framework (DRF), and would like the API clients to be able to easily enumerate the `descriptions` associated with the model. As it stands, the clients have to reference each logical 'index' manually, which makes the code repetitive.

My DRF serializer code is currently like this:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
```

There are a fixed number of `descriptions` for each `Widget`, and their ordering is important.

Is there a clean way to expose these fields as a collection on the Model object?

Answer (score 0):

It really was as easy as adding a method to the Model class that returns the fields as a sequence, and then (for API clients), manually specifying that new method as a `field` to serialize.

So the Model definition becomes:

```
from django.db import models

class Widget(models.Model):
    description_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def descriptions(self):
        return self.description_1, self.description_2, self.description_3
```

And the DRF serializer is updated like:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ('url', 'descriptions',)
```

This causes the API to return a JSON array for `descriptions` and omit all of the individual `description_x` fields.